# How Many Filters Can We Have -- LINUX QOS

Tags: linux, bandwidth, qos, tc

I am doing Qos on Linux server using TC. According to the grammar of tc tool, the handle of a filter must be between 800::001 and 800::FFF. And because 0XFFF equals 4095 in decimal, so we can only have at most 4095 filters, it this true?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a filter has a handle in a form of HHH:HH:HHH, so there can be 0xfff hash tables, every table can hold up to 0xff cells, every cell can contain up to 0xfff filters.